# Where can I find the latex Local Guide (for TeXLive on Mint)

Tags: texlive, linux

I am working through the "[The Not So Short
Introduction to LATEX2ε](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf)" by Oetiker et al.

It contains dozens of references to a so-called "Local Guide", that would clarify some more system-specific questions (typically exactly the stuff that I get stuck with).
The reference reads:

> Each LATEX installation should provide a so-called LATEX Local Guide,
>   which explains the things that are special to the local system. It should
>   be contained in a file called local.tex. Unfortunately, some lazy sysops
>   do not provide such a document. In this case, go and ask your local
>   LATEX guru for help.

Now, I am my own "sysop", and I installed TexLive using apt-get on Linux Mint 17.3.

Searching Google for the latex local guide with my setting didn't bring anything useful up.
I also searched my system with `find / -name 'local.tex' 2>/dev/null` with no result.

Where can I find this file?

Comment: The idea of a 'local guide' mainly comes from the time when TeX would be installed on a multi-user system with an administrator. Nowadays most installations look very similar (on Linux a version of TeX Live). Perhaps you might edit in what exactly it is you are after and we might eb able to help more precisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using texlive then effectively the "local guide" is the texlive manual which you can get by

```
texdoc texlive
```

or online (for tl2014)

http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/texlive/texlive-en/texlive-en.pdf

Comment: Ok, I see. Will work through that then, too.